# I cannot define a function inside my class

Tags: python, function, oop, tkinter, python-class

I am trying to define a function inside of my class but still on line 31 'command=clear' does not see my function i created below. Please help, thank you!!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import googletrans
import textblob
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox


class Translate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.geometry = self.root.geometry('880x500')

    def design(self):
        text_box = Text(self.root,height=15,width=40)
        text_box.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)
        
        translate_button = Button(self.root,text='Translate',font=('Arial',20))
        translate_button.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=20)

        translated_text = Text(self.root,height=15,width=40)
        translated_text.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=20)

        self.original_language = ttk.Combobox(self.root,width=50,value=language_list)
        self.original_language.current(21)
        self.original_language.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.translated_language = ttk.Combobox(self.root,width=50,value=language_list)
        self.translated_language.current(26)
        self.translated_language.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.clear_button = Button(self.root,text='Clear',font=('Arial',18),command=clear)
        self.clear_button.grid(row=2,column=1) 

    def clear(self):
        self.original_language.delete(1.0,END)
        self.translated_language.delete(1.0,END)

    def language_list(self):
        return

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Translate()
    t1.design()
```

I cannot make the functions work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `command=self.clear`

Comment: Line23 and 27 should be `value=self.language_list`.

Comment: You should also remove `self.root.mainloop()` from your class and put it in your __name__ section.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Don't used Wildcard `from tkinter import *` Why because when you do that, you load all of `tkinter's` namespace into your module's namespace.

Edit: Forgotten to add function.

Is this what it looks like?

- Line 23 and 27 should be `value=self.language_list`.
- line 24 and 28, the index to zero. Should be
  self.translated_language.current(0)
- In line 31, shoulde be `self.clear`
- In line 41, comment out `#self.root.mainloop()`
- Add in line 46, `tk.mainloop()`

In line 34, clear function:

```
def clear(self):
    self.original_language.delete(1.0,END)
    self.translated_language.delete(1.0,END)
```

Change this:

```
def clear(self):
    self.original_language.delete(1.0,END)
    self.translated_language.delete(1.0,END)
```

to:

```
def clear(self):
    self.original_language.delete('0', tk.END)
    self.translated_language.delete('0', tk.END)
```

Snippet re-work using prefix as `tk`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import googletrans
import textblob
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox


class Translate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.geometry = self.root.geometry('880x500')

    def design(self):
        text_box = tk.Text(self.root,height=15,width=40)
        text_box.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)
        
        translate_button = tk.Button(self.root,text='Translate',font=('Arial',20))
        translate_button.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=20)

        translated_text = tk.Text(self.root,height=15,width=40)
        translated_text.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=20)

        self.original_language = ttk.Combobox(self.root,width=50,value=self.language_list)
        self.original_language.current(0)
        self.original_language.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.translated_language = ttk.Combobox(self.root,width=50,value=self.language_list)
        self.translated_language.current(0)
        self.translated_language.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self.root,text='Clear',font=('Arial',18),command=self.clear)
        self.clear_button.grid(row=2,column=1) 

    def clear(self):
        self.original_language.delete('0', END)
        self.translated_language.delete('0', END)

    def language_list(self):
        return

    #self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Translate()
    t1.design()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hey this post is good but the original problem is the `self.clear` should be explains a bit so the user can understand why the function "appeared" to not be called.

Comment: I left out something. Thanks. I will update

Comment: I was speaking more on explaining the actual problem as to why the code didn't work with the function call. (IE. Due to the `self.` missing the command was not actually saving a reference to the class method. By adding the `self.` into the function call we properly save a reference to the method). That said we should also get rid of `from tkinter import *` as we are already doing `import tkinter as tk`.

Comment: `self.language_list` is a function, so what is the point of assigning it to `value` option of `ttk.Combobox`?